# Difference between systemd wpa_supplicant.service and wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service?

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, systemd, raspberry-pi, wpa-supplicant

Using Arch Linux on a Raspberry Pi and a USB Wi-Fi dongle, I can get Wi-Fi working by enabling the `wpa_supplicant@wlan0` systemd service. This uses the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant@wlan0.conf` file and specifies the `wlan0` interface.

I understand the `wpa_supplicant` systemd service does the same thing, except it autodetects the wireless interface, but starting this service instead doesn't work, even when I have a valid `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file.

How would I use the `wpa_supplicant` systemd service to autodetect the wireless interface and setup my Wi-Fi?

If autodetection is not what the `wpa_supplicant` service does, what is the point of the `wpa_supplicant` service vs the `wpa_supplicant@interface` service?

Comment: Try with the configuration file `wpa_supplicant@.conf`

Comment: I believe `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant@wlan0.conf` should be `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf`. In other words, the service uses the `@` but the conf file uses `-`.

Answer (score 8):

As stated on [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#At_boot_.28systemd.29), the wpa_supplicant.service file is for DBus aware services, so it will be autodetected by NetworkManager for example. As I imagine you are not using NetworkManager, either you have to write a program/script that will use DBus information to lift the interface or use the specific interface version wpa_supplicant@.service. Quoting:

> The wpa_supplicant package provides multiple systemd service files:
>
> **wpa_supplicant.service** - uses D-Bus, recommended for NetworkManager
> users.
>
> **wpa_supplicant@.service** - accepts the interface name as an
> argument and starts the wpa_supplicant daemon for this interface. It
> reads a /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-interface.conf
> configuration file.
>
> **wpa_supplicant-nl80211@.service** - also interface
> specific, but explicitly forces the nl80211 driver (see below). The
> configuration file path is
> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-nl80211-interface.conf.
>
> **wpa_supplicant-wired@.service** - also interface specific, uses the
> wired driver. The configuration file path is
> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wired-interface.conf.

[image: Reference]

Answer (score 2):

The `wpa_supplicant@.service` installed with the *wpa_supplicant* package from pacman at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@.service`  is a dynamic service file which allows a service such as `wpa_supplicant@wlan0` to be managed. It will look for a wpa_supplicant configuration file at `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf`, where the *wlan0* in the filename corresponds to the *wlan0* in the service name.

If your nic uses the nl80211 driver, you may use the `wpa_supplicant-nl80211@.service` in the same way. The configuration file it looks for is `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-nl80211-<interface>.conf`